# Code completion in groovlets?

Tags: eclipse, groovy, groovlet

Why doesn't eclipse provide proper code completion for implicit objects in a groovlet -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`html` is an instance of `MarkupBuilder` and although one might think it has all the html methods (h1, pre so on), it does not have any such method. It just generates the tag by the name of method. So in effect `html.sillyvalue()` is also valid and would result in `' tag. Is such case autocompletion is not possible.

To alleviate the problem you can provide DSLD files (which you might already be aware of). this is quite interesting blog on the topic: http://en.appsatori.eu/2011/05/writing-groovy-dsl-descriptors-dsld-for.html